# dBeaver doesn't show me all the results from a Vertica table

Tags: sql, resultset, vertica, dbeaver

I am trying to get a list of users, who submitted a specific event in a website, however when I run the query, I am not getting the full result set - for example, I found 2 users who had the event (and I used the same conditions), but are not in the result set.

The script looks like:

```
select userid
    , Date
from c 
where year(c.Date) = 2018
    and week(c.Date) = (week(getdate()) - 1) 
    and Event in ('existing', 'submit_existing', 'submit_new')
group by 1,2
```

Can anybody give me a hint what might be the issue?

If anything is unclear or if you have any questions, let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Remove your conditions one at a time until the excluded records show up in the query results and then make adjustments to your selection criteria.  I'd suggest starting with the last condition - force the Event column values to lowercase since that's what you're selecting.

Comment: Thanks, @dgg you can see what was the issue in my answer :)

Answer (score 8):

https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1708

`Ctrl+Alt+Shift+A` or right click menu: **Execute** => **Select all rows**.

Answer (score 1):

so I managed to find the answer!

The reason for my problem is that in dbeaver there is a `Maximum result-set size` filed and if you have a lower number than the result set you are expecting - you will get duplicates and missing data, because each time it runs it shows a new results set.

Hope this can help somebody!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to change the default number of returned rows for all future times

[image: configure the default number of rows returned]

In dbeaver, you have to go to the "window" menu, then select preferences, then navigate to Editors / Results